# Router navigation fails to load angular component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am new to building web applications using Angular and unable to resolve the following issue.

I am trying to build a web application that expects the user of the application to first login and on successful login will redirect the application to one of the home pages.

The issue that I am currently facing is that even after successful login (which I have verified by the nodejs http response 200 and the application token being set in the Local storage) the application fails to load the component to be loaded after successful login.

I can see that the URL does change to the load the expected Angular component. But despite URL change, the angular component does not render itself.

Following is the code that I have used -

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.routing.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: SignInComponent },
    { path: 'recruitment/home', component: RecruitmentHomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'recruitment/home' }
];
```

sign-in.component.ts

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.myForm.value.username, this.myForm.value.password)
      .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate(['recruitment/home']);
      },
      error => {
        // this.alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

recruitment-home.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1> Welcome to recruitment home </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h2> Here is where all the action will be present </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have verified that the login service is successful by looking into the chrome -> Inspect -> Application -> Local storage

```
{success: true,…}
status
:
"You are successfully logged in!"
success
:
true
token
:
"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YTczNmZkYTYyOGVjODMxZjQ0NDAyYmkjadfkajlkjuadfkjljadf.vL1DNHaz9DZo2j7yAVks4oAUwAR6lAs5qIWDuwVrX7o"
```

The  in the app.component.html which on application load renders the sign-in.component.html fails to load the recruitment-home.component.html after successful login within the same space.

I have tried using stackblitz online tool to verify the code and a strange thing was observed. When i try to run the same code from within stackblitz and use the 'Open' option to render the output along side the code, I am able to see the recruitment-home.component.html being loaded as required. However using the same stackblitz tool, when i choose the option to render the output in a new window, the same issue that I see when I run the application locally is observed.

I am not sure how to debug this issue. Any pointers around this would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Can you try with this.router.navigate(['/recruitment', 'home'])?

Comment: You mentioned you used stackblitz and experiences the same behavior, perhaps provide that to us?

Comment: Hi Christian, I tried the option as you suggested and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is now resolved. I just realized that the recruitment-home.component.html row did not have the style="margin-top: 50px" property set. When I added the property, I was able to see the component being rendered as required.

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 250px">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3> Welcome to recruitment home </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3> Here is where all the action will be present </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```